# Как получить данные из функции?

Tags: javascript, return

Нужно в другом месте кода вызвать эту функцию и получить данные которые вернул сервер! Как это сделать? Пробовал сделать `return this.responseText;`, но что-то не помогло... Что я делаю не так?

```
    function sendFunction(url,params){ 


    var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;

    var xhru = new XHR();

    xhru.open('POST', ''+HOST+''+url+'', true);

    xhru.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 

    xhru.onload = function() {
        var ans = JSON.parse(this.responseText);



        return this.responseText;
    }

    xhru.onerror = function() {
        // alert( 'Ошибка ' + this.status );
        //console.log( 'Ошибка ' + this.status);
    }

    xhru.send(params);


}
```

Comment: запрос на сервер вещь асинхронная, ответ придет когда-то или не придет. стандартный подход - передать в функцию запроса другую функцию - callback, и вызвать ее когда придет ответ, т.е в  onload

Comment: `function sendFunction(url,params,callback)` и после выполните коллбек (это функция) в `onload`

Comment: Как писали выше можно использовать callback, но также можно использовать и Промисы. Т.е. в теле функции написать `return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{/*тело функции*/})` а в onload прописать `resolve(this.responseText)`. Если произошла ошибка `reject(this.status)`. Соответственно при вызове пишем так `sendFunction(url, params).then((result)=>{/*делаем что-то с результатом*/}`. Подробнее о Промисах тут: https://learn.javascript.ru/promise

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц попробовал как вы описали, поставил callback() в xhru.onload = function() {  callback(); } пишет ошибка и функция  callback не найдена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оставил внутри то, что вас интересует. Фишка в том что вы не получаете данные с функции, а просто заталкиваете в нее еще функцию, которая выполниться, когда запрос выполнится, т к сам запрос асинхронный.

```js
function sendFunction(url,callbackSuccess,callbackError){ 
    var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;
    var xhru = new XHR();
    xhru.open('GET', url, true);
    xhru.onload = function() {
        callbackSuccess(this.responseText);
    }

    xhru.onerror = function() {
        callbackError()
    }

    xhru.send();
}

sendFunction("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",function(res){console.log(res)});
```

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev пожалуйста, удачи в изучении